# Add class when date today passed on a var

Tags: jquery, datetime, case

I have a function, but I need this function better.
Somehow its not working. When i use text its working, but thats not the way i want it.

```
switch(sStage) {
    case 'pre':
        var rData = '\n' +
            '   <table class="cssTblRow "><tr>                                                                                                  \n' +
            '     <td class="cssTdRow  cssDSVOntslag cssPatBSN" data-ontslag="{{DSVOKONTSLAGDATUM}}">{{DSVOKONTSLAGDATUM}}</td>                                     \n' +
            '   </tr></table>                                                                                              \n'
        return rData;
    case 'post':
        $('.cssDSVOntslag').each(function(i, obj) {
            switch ($(obj).data("ontslag").toLowerCase()) {
                case '10-9-2018 11:00:00' :
                    $(obj).addClass("cssSpecMDL");
                    break;
                case '8-9-2018 11:00:00':
                    $(obj).addClass("cssDuurRed");
                    break;
                default:
            }
        });
    // code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

{{DSVOKONTSLAGDATUM}} is the var date.
4-9-2018 20:00:00

So i need to add a class when its over that time. (4-9-2018 20:00:00)

Could someone help me?